# ProgressBar not working on one device but fine on another

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I am using this piece of code below to make a progress bar. The bar works fine (a function updates the progress) on a Samsung S5 running Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow API 23). The bar updates and the progress is shown correctly.

I also generated an APK of my code and manually installed it on a Wiley Fox Swift X2 running Android 7.1.1 (API 25). The app works except for the progress bars do not update. They are visible but no update occurs.

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressbar0"
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:foregroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
android:progress="1" />
```

```
ProgressBar bar0 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar0);

bar0.setMax(total_answered);

bar0.setProgress(answered_0);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I checked on Android 7.1.2, Emulators 7.1.1 and 7.0. It's working fine. Please, check on emulator with 7.1.1 and if the bug repeats, provide the full code, I'll look at it.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked further than the widget itself and found that for some reason, a piece of prior code that gives the values to set the bar are not being declared...so I am going to have a look at that. Thanks for the suggestion...the "provide full code" made me think a bit further out of the box as it were. If I still struggle, I will come back. Thanks :).